# IAccessible Implementation - Accessible Name only in Control Window?

Tags: winforms, delphi, delphi-xe2, ui-automation

I'm currently trying to implement the IAccessible Interface in my Custom Controls, to be able to automatically test my GUI.
I was able to implement the Interface and create and use a `StdAccessibleObject` as Proxy for all properties/functions I don't want to change. But, it's not really working as I want it to.

Every control accessed by MSAA gets his own Window-Control, which contains the control itself. In my case, just this window gets the name property I applied, the real control (in my case a derivation of `TCustomEdit`) has the standard value.

[image]

Does someone have an idea **how to append the accessible name to both control and control-window**, or even just the control itself?

Thanks in advance for your time.

*Below my code.*

---

I created an own class which contains the functions of IAccessible, an instance of this class ist created in my Edit after the Handle was created.

```
TXCustomEdit = class(TCustomMaskEdit, IXControl, ... , IAccessible)

...

strict private
  FAccessible: IAccessible;
  ...
  procedure WMGetMSAAObject(var Message : TMessage); message WM_GETOBJECT;
  ...
private
  procedure CreateHandle(); override;
  ...
protected
  property Accessible: IAccessible read FAccessible implements IAccessible;
  ...
end;

implementation
...

procedure TXCustomEdit.CreateHandle;
begin
  inherited CreateHandle;
  FAccessible := TXControlEigenschaften.Create(Self);
end;

procedure TXCustomEdit.WMGetMSAAObject(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  if Assigned(FAccessible) then
    (FAccessible as TXControlEigenschaften).WMGetMSAAObject(Message);
end;
```

The declaration of my class:

```
TXControlEigenschaften = class (TInterfacedObject, IAccessible)
strict private
  FControl: IXControl;
  FAccessible: IAccessible;

  // IAccessible
  function Get_accParent(out ppdispParent: IDispatch): HResult; stdcall;
  function Get_accChildCount(out pcountChildren: Integer): HResult; stdcall;
  function Get_accChild(varChild: OleVariant; out ppdispChild: IDispatch): HResult; stdcall;
  function Get_accName(varChild: OleVariant; out pszName: WideString): HResult; stdcall;
  function Get_accValue(varChild: OleVariant; out pszValue: WideString): HResult; stdcall;
  function Get_accDescription(varChild: OleVariant; out pszDescription: WideString): HResult; stdcall;
  function Get_accRole(varChild: OleVariant; out pvarRole: OleVariant): HResult; stdcall;
  function Get_accState(varChild: OleVariant; out pvarState: OleVariant): HResult; stdcall;
  function Get_accHelp(varChild: OleVariant; out pszHelp: WideString): HResult; stdcall;
  function Get_accHelpTopic(out pszHelpFile: WideString; varChild: OleVariant;
                                                      out pidTopic: Integer): HResult; stdcall;
  function Get_accKeyboardShortcut(varChild: OleVariant; out pszKeyboardShortcut: WideString): HResult; stdcall;
  function Get_accFocus(out pvarChild: OleVariant): HResult; stdcall;
  function Get_accSelection(out pvarChildren: OleVariant): HResult; stdcall;
  function Get_accDefaultAction(varChild: OleVariant; out pszDefaultAction: WideString): HResult; stdcall;
  function accSelect(flagsSelect: Integer; varChild: OleVariant): HResult; stdcall;
  function accLocation(out pxLeft: Integer; out pyTop: Integer; out pcxWidth: Integer;
                                           out pcyHeight: Integer; varChild: OleVariant): HResult; stdcall;
  function accNavigate(navDir: Integer; varStart: OleVariant; out pvarEndUpAt: OleVariant): HResult; stdcall;
  function accHitTest(xLeft: Integer; yTop: Integer; out pvarChild: OleVariant): HResult; stdcall;
  function accDoDefaultAction(varChild: OleVariant): HResult; stdcall;
  function Set_accName(varChild: OleVariant; const pszName: WideString): HResult; stdcall;
  function Set_accValue(varChild: OleVariant; const pszValue: WideString): HResult; stdcall;

  function GetIDsOfNames(const IID: TGUID; Names: Pointer;
    NameCount, LocaleID: Integer; DispIDs: Pointer): HResult; stdcall;
  function GetTypeInfo(Index, LocaleID: Integer; out TypeInfo): HResult; stdcall;
  function GetTypeInfoCount(out Count: Integer): HResult; stdcall;
  function Invoke(DispID: Integer; const IID: TGUID; LocaleID: Integer;
    Flags: Word; var Params; VarResult, ExcepInfo, ArgErr: Pointer): HResult; stdcall;

public
  constructor Create(aControl: IXControl);

  procedure WMGetMSAAObject(var Message : TMessage); message WM_GETOBJECT;
end;
```

Important implementations:

```
constructor TXControlEigenschaften.Create(aControl: IXControl);
var
  p: Pointer;
begin
  inherited Create();
  FControl := aControl;
  CreateStdAccessibleObject((FControl.GetOwnControl as TWinControl).Handle, OBJID_CLIENT, IID_IAccessible, p);
  FAccessible := IAccessible(p);
end;

procedure TXControlEigenschaften.WMGetMSAAObject(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  if (Message.Msg = WM_GETOBJECT) then
    Message.Result := LresultFromObject(IID_IAccessible, Message.WParam, Self)
  else
    Message.Result := DefWindowProc((FControl.GetOwnControl as TWinControl).Handle, Message.Msg, Message.WParam, Message.LParam);
end;

function TXControlEigenschaften.Get_accName(varChild: OleVariant; out pszName: WideString): HResult;
begin
  pszName := FControl.Name;
  Result := S_OK;
end;
```

All other functions of the interface are implemented via my "proxy", e.g.:

```
function TXControlEigenschaften.Get_accParent(out ppdispParent: IDispatch): HResult;
begin
  Result := FAccessible.Get_accParent(ppdispParent);
end;
```

Comment: I am lost. What is the actual problem?

Comment: the problem is that the name i'm adding inside the `get_accName` is only visible when i select the control window, not when i select the control itself

Answer (score 1):

Just found out, that having the name only in the window control is no problem, because the UI Test Generator always searches in both MSAA-Objects to identify the control. That's why this question is kinda unnecessary.

If somebody knows the real answer for this question, I will accept it, but there is no need to solve this because it is no problem for my use case.